# How to create custom control tool for textbox validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a tool like textbox validation so how to create textbox validate tool in asp.net c#

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="txtLastName"
  ErrorMessage="Last name is a required field."
  ForeColor="Red">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: i want to create custom toolof textbox validator....if i use only dll file to other application also

Comment: export your code as DLL file, then add it as reference file. you may read more about how to create a DLL

Comment: there is no custom control tool, else the exist in ASP by default,
your question is not clear and you do not understood what do you want.
last answer try to using regular expression